# Hierarchy of classes, trying to implement functions at the base level

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, lambda

I have to design a hierarchy of classes, for example:

```
class Animal{
  speak();
  name();
  toString();
...
}

class Dog : public Animal {
  ...;
}
```

I can choose whether to implement them like this:

```
class Animal{
  virtual speak() = 0;
  virtual name() = 0;
  virtual toString() = 0 ;
...
}

class Dog : public Animal {
  speak(){ ... }
  name(){ ... }
  toString(){ ... }
}
```

OR, exercising in pointers to functions and lambdas... like this:

```
class Animal{
  speak( s(); );
  name( n(); );
  toString( t(); );
...
protected:
 std::function<...> s();
 std::function<...> n();
 std::function<...> t();
}

class Dog : public Animal {
  Dog(){
    s() = ...;
    n() = ...:
    t() = ...:
  }
}
```

But, in the second scenario the base class wouldn't be abstract, and I'm not sure this would be a good idea... 
Is the second case a very useless implementation? 
Can you explain me why?

Comment: Your 1st scenario doesn't represent an abstract class either?

Comment: I should make the functions pure virtuals... isn't it?

Comment: Of course, if you want an abstract class.

Comment: I've modified the post. Could you give me some explanation about the differences brought by the two implementations?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a choice between the following methods:

**First Method**

```
class Animal{
  virtual speak() = 0;
  ...
};

class Dog : public Animal {
  speak(){ ... }
  ...
};
```

**Second Method**

```
class Animal{
  speak( s(); );
  ...
protected:
  std::function<...> s();
  ...
};

class Dog : public Animal {
  Dog(){
    s() = ...;
    ...
  }
};
```

Prefer the first method.

In the second method, you are implementing your version of virtual function dispatch instead of letting the compiler do it for you.

Comment: I think _second method_ is a bit ambigous here. There's at least no first.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach allows changing the behaviour of the objects *on-the-fly*. E.g. you can change how an animal speaks (even after you've instantiated an object). If that's all you've got it's even questionable whether you need separate classes for the animals. Just create a factory.

If you don't need this *flexibility*, it's certainly an overkill and added complexity and you should just use virtual methods.